# Target parent windows element by the elements name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a system that creates light box popups in order to deal with user requests appropriately, and for this, elements are built dynamically on the parent window.

When a user clicks a link, it has an onclick action that needs to refer to the parent window in order to get the desired information, but the issue lies in the fact that it does not have an id and it is not an option to add one to the elements themselves.

I have tried many things, including but not exhaustive of:

```
var obj = window.parent.document.{name};
var obj = jQuery(window.parent.document.{name});
var obj = window.top.document.{name};
```

The element is a simple hidden input element that is built at time of page load and looks something akin to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{name}" value="1|2|3" />
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this goal are greatly appreciated.

*Note:* Any use of `{name}` within this are merely to show where the elements name is and not that it IS that

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementsByName('{name}')[0]`?

Comment: Can you not select by name? `$('input[name="{name}"]')`

Comment: @gabe, that I never thought of, I will attempt

Comment: @gabe, would you be willing to add that as an answer with a little description for future readers and I will mark as accepted ASAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select elements (which have 'special' attribute value) with:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="{name}"]')
```

or, with the own selector of the attribute:

```
document.getElementsByName('{name}')[0]
```